# Где можно посмотреть позицию своего приложения?

Tags: android, google-play

Где можно бесплатно посмотреть позицию своего приложения в Play Market по определенным запросам?

Comment: Я обычно в маркете по ключевым словам в поиске смотрел на каком месте приложение

Comment: Неплохо помогает App Anie https://www.appannie.com/ (но полезные фичи в основном в платной версии), есть еще ряд сервисов менее функциональных

Comment: @SergeMarkov, про АппАнни знаю. Но как Вы и сказали - за бесплатно мало полезности)

Answer (score 2):

Если **апанька** не подходит, тогда попробуйте воспользоваться [**distimo**](http://www.distimo.com/) или [**appfigures**](http://appfigures.com).